# Databricks structured streaming write to managed table

Tags: databricks, spark-structured-streaming, databricks-unity-catalog

In Databricks structured streaming is it possible to write a stream using the writeStream API to a unity catalog managed table?

I'm able to write the stream to an external table in ADLS Gen2 fine, but when it try to write it to a managed table using .start(catalog.schema.table) the stream writes my checkpoints correctly but nothing is written to the managed table. I'm unsure if I'm doing something wrong, or if this is in fact not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that instead of .start("catalog"."schema"."table") I needed to use .table("catalog"."schema"."table").

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).